# Confusion in 'history' and 'historical' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

In [my puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28023/the-real-story-of-two-mischievous-brothers?noredirect=1#comment83324_28023), I want to use the tag [historical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical) which has the description "primarily built around a historical situation or event. Often it concerns famous persons or weird and unexpected happenings." But when I chose it then it converted into a [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag which has description "The history of puzzles and their creation, as well as any methodologies which have developed over time. For history themed puzzles use [historical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical)."

What should I do now? Should I use the [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag which clearly says that I should use [historical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical) for history themed puzzles?

---

More puzzles which should be having the [historical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical) tag but are currently having [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag are given below:

- [Turning wine into water](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/turning-wine-into-water)
- [A man possesses a large quantity of stamps](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28490/a-man-possesses-a-large-quantity-of-stamps)
- [The grazing cows of Sir Isaac Newton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28342/the-grazing-cows-of-sir-isaac-newton)
- [What could be it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25702/what-could-be-it)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like virtually all of the puzzles tagged [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) are about world history, *not* puzzle history.

I think the best thing it this case would be to update the tag wiki for [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) so that it matches [historical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical), and create a new [puzzle-history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-history) tag for those rare instances that are actually talking about puzzle history.

Comment: On the contrary, I only see three puzzles tagged [tag:history] that shouldn't be, and they're all from after the tags were merged (Jan 6). The rest of the history-themed puzzles have the correct [tag:historical] tag. I think the tags should be unmerged.

Comment: To me, "history" says "This puzzle is related to history or historical events". I second the [tag:puzzle-history] tag.

Comment: In my opinion we should not be making too many tags...three tags just for history are unnecessary. So just like @f'' I also vote for unmerging instead of making another tag.